# How to project WRF data (lat/lon) onto ArcGIS maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I have climate data generated using the WRF model, in lat/lon format (lambert conformal projection), in an Excel file.

I'm looking to project / overlay this data onto a map of the UK using ArcGIS, however the projection is only showing as a single point, and not over the UK!

Has anyone got any experience of overlaying WRF output (in lat/lon format) onto a GIS map?

Comment: There are several WRF-related questions already. You might want to look at them to see if any apply. If the data is really lat/lon (in decimal degrees), it can't be in LCC. What coordinate system was assigned when the data was added to ArcMap? It might have defaulted to BNG, which would be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having the same problem with a NetCDF file of the same data, when I convert it to a shapefile in GIS no coordinates are detected so it cant project. I've checked with the person who ran the WRF script and they have confirmed its LCC, so not sure what the lat/lon values I have are? Yes it did default to BNG as that's what the baselayer map is in.